# Reading file and store data with linked list error c

Tags: c, linked-list

My project is to **read from a file of .txt** that contains the names of students, and I have to input the scores of them (up to 5 inputs), and the **names should be linked list** as shown in my attachment picture.

[image: data structure of names and scores]

A problem that I faced is that, when I try to enter the third student's score data, the program will crash, I concludes it as a problem of overflow of memory, yet I don't know how can I delete any part to release the memory since all of the linked list is used to point to each other.

I'll be appreciate that if anyone can tell me what might be the problem. And sorry for my poor English, thank you very much.

my code and the txt file as below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct nodeName {
    char *name;
    struct nodeName *linkToName;
    struct nodeScore *linkToScore;
};

struct nodeScore {
    int score;
    struct nodeScore *linkNextScore;
};

struct nodeName *insertName(struct nodeName *ptr, char *nameIn);
struct nodeName *insertScore(struct nodeName *ptr);
void displayList(struct nodeName *ptr);

struct nodeName *insertName(struct nodeName *ptr, char *nameIn) {
    struct nodeName *n = (struct nodeName *)malloc(sizeof(struct nodeName));
    int counter = 0;
    int scoreTemp;
    char checkInt;
    char *tag;
    struct nodeScore *tempS;

    tag = nameIn;
    n->name = tag;

    while (counter < 5) {
        struct nodeScore *s = (struct nodeScore *)malloc(sizeof(struct nodeScore));
        counter++;
        printf("Enter %d Score of %s:", counter, tag);
        if (scanf("%d%c", &scoreTemp, &checkInt) != 2 || checkInt == 'n') {
            printf("\nEnd saving %s's score.\n", tag);
            break;
        }
        s->score = scoreTemp;
        if (n->linkToScore == NULL)  //for the first link to node of score.
            n->linkToScore = s;
        else
            tempS->linkNextScore = s;
        s->linkNextScore = NULL;
        tempS = s;
    }
    ptr = n;
    return ptr;
}

int main() {
    FILE *nameF = fopen("HW5_26.txt", "r");
    char input[512];
    char *SingleName;
    struct nodeName *p1, *temp;
    int testN1 = 0;

    while (fgets(input, 512, nameF)) {  //get file line by line
        SingleName = strtok(input, " "); //if 'space' or 'New line', save as a single name.
        printf("\n");
        printf("Name# %d = %s\n", ++testN1, SingleName);
        printf("\n");

        p1 = insertName(p1, SingleName);
        temp = p1;

        while (SingleName != NULL) {
            SingleName = strtok(NULL, " ");  //put n name into SingleName
            if (SingleName != NULL) {
                printf("___________________________\n\n");
                printf("Name# %d = %s\n", ++testN1, SingleName);
                printf("\n");
                p1 = insertName(p1, SingleName);
                temp->linkToName = p1;
                temp = p1;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the content of **HW5_26.txt**

```
Albert Steve David Mike
Andrew Joanne Chris Fred
Dennis Leo Fred Frances
Dave Hua Sarah
```

Comment: Please consider removing the `c++` tag.

Comment: There is no such thing as "c/c++". Either use C (no iostreams) or use proper C++ (iostreams, classes, encapsulation, constructors/destructors, the whole enchilada).

Comment: You have a lot of problem here. Bad design, no check of error, you cast for nothing and more. I am sure that you can solve this by yourself. Try separate your task. You have prototype of insert score and display but your don't write it ! I don't see where is score in your txt file. To solve this you need a true lexer, `scanf()` has limits. You start with strtok, continue is a very good function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are major design problems in your code:

- You should allow for multiple names: `Albert Einstein` is 2 words.  The names file should contain one full name per line.  Read it with `fgets()` and remove the trailing newline with `str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = '\0';`
- You should read all marks as a single line and parse them with `strtol()`. When the pointer updated by `strtol()` is not moved, you have read all marks.
- Your code for inserting a name does not append the node to the `Student` list.
- Function `insertName()` should duplicate the string with `strdup()` or equivalent.  As coded, all nodes' names point to some part of the same buffer in the `main` function, that is overwritten by each call to `fgets()`.
- You declare an `insertScore` function but you do not use it.  It would be better to move the code to separate function for clarity.
- You should check the return values of `fopen` and `malloc` to handle errors gracefully.
- You can use `typedef` to remove the `struct` keywords and make the code eaier to read.